# Is there an annotation similar to @JsonCreator for setters that accept more than one parameter?

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have a serializable object with lots of fields, some of which are mandatory, and others optional. To make this object easy to use, I took a shot at the [Builder Pattern with a Twist](https://blog.jayway.com/2012/02/07/builder-pattern-with-a-twist/). This works great, but some of the resulting Builder's methods take more than one parameter. Here's an example:

```
@JsonProperty("foo")
public Builder setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    return this;
}

public Builder setBarAndZip(@JsonProperty("bar") String bar, @JsonProperty("zip") String zip) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.zip = zip;
    return this;
}
```

Provided I annotate my parent class (the class that this Builder creates) with `@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.Builder.class)`, Jackson handles `foo` with no issue. However, it doesn't call `setBarAndZip(...)`, and as a consequence, neither `bar` or `zip` get deserialized.

I've found that I can get around this by putting my `@JsonProperty` annotations directly on the private fields of the builder, rather than on the setters, so I have a work around, but is there a better way?

Constructors can accept multiple parameters with the help of the `@JsonCreator` annotation. Is there an equivalent annotation that I could apply to `setBarAndZip(...)` that would let Jackson see the `@JsonProperty` annotations on its parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jackson-user Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/o0FY3wkydEk) page:

> Tatu Saloranta
>
> No, currently there is no way to have what amounts to 
>   multiple-argument setters. From annotation perspective it should be 
>   possible to just use `@JsonSetter` for such methods, but internally 
>   those are not yet supported.  They would be nice to support, but would
>   likely require lots of work  due to internal assumptions that each
>   setter method only handles  single property.
>
> -+ Tatu +-